# Can you test for significant changes across 4 data points that represent the average cycle time in 1 month?

Tags: time-series, confidence-interval

I have 4 data points that represent the average cycle time for a process in one month.  The data is of the full population, not a sample.  I am trying to determine if there has been a significant change over those 4 months.  Here are the data points, with 't' representing the month and 'ct' the cycle time:

```
  t    ct
1 1 48.33
2 2 42.71
3 3 33.42
4 4 34.17
```

I have tried a linear regression model.  Here is my code and the results from that model:

```
#create data set
ct <- c(48.33, 42.71, 33.42, 34.17)
t <- c(1,2,3,4)
df <- data.frame(t,ct)
#linear model
mod1 <- lm(ct ~ t, data = df)
summary(mod1)
```

Model results:

```
Call:
lm(formula = ct ~ t, data = df)

Residuals:
     1      2      3      4 
 0.907  0.464 -3.649  2.278 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)   52.600      3.828  13.739  0.00526 **
t             -5.177      1.398  -3.703  0.06580 . 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.126 on 2 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8727,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8091 
F-statistic: 13.71 on 1 and 2 DF,  p-value: 0.0658
```

While this shows a p-value close to 0.05, I don't think this approach is valid since I only have 4 data points and the diagnostic plots indicate violations of the assumption of normality.

I have also created a time series object with the data and tried the MannKendall test:

```
#create a time series object
ct_ts <- ts(ct, start = c(2023,1), frequency = 12)
MannKendall(ct_ts)
```

Results:

```
tau = -0.667, 2-sided pvalue =0.30818
```

This also shows a p-value > 0.05, however I have read that you should have at least 8-10 data points for the test.

Lastly, I have considered creating confidence intervals for each mean and seeing if there is any overlap.  The basis for this is a paper that I read by [David Edelman](https://doi.org/10.2307/2684348) on "A Confidence Interval for the Center of an Unknown Unimodal Distribution Based on a Sample of Size 1."  The application here, I think, would be to treat each data point as our sample of size 1 and calculate the respective CI.  If they overlap, then we could suggest that there are not significant differences and that the points come from the same distribution with any difference attributable to chance variation.

Is there a better way to approach this?  Perhaps with a one-sample T-test?

Comment: The easiest and most informative way to test for changes would be based on the original, raw data before averaging. This would add a standard deviation to the information.

Comment: Thanks @MikeHunter.  Unfortunately, all I have are the monthly averages.  Without the raw data, I'm wondering what the best approach would be.

Comment: Because there's no such thing as a "full population" for a *process,* it's unclear what you are trying to ask.  The question seems to come down to testing a sequence of four numbers for some kind of "change."  Besides  being vague, it's impossible to answer. But even if you are looking to test the slope of a linear regression, the assumptions you will need to check (little if any serial correlation or heteroscedasticity) cannot be established.  There's no way, absent extremely strong unstated assumptions, you can attain statistical significance here.

Comment: By "full population", I simply mean all of the available data.  This wasn't a sample of the process.  All of the outcomes (cycle times) were used to calculate the monthly average.

Comment: If, along with these four averages, you had *any* values to indicate the variability of the numbers they summarize, then you could make some progress (although you would still have to make some assumptions about the statistical characteristics of the underlying process).  But with four numbers alone there's little you can do.